# How disable view page functionality and revert to pure view with master display?

Tags: views, routes

> On view setting page
>
> [image]

I have view with menu link and path. I want to turn it off, revert to basic view `master`. I've try to remove menu, but didn't change anything. Then I try to remove path but is mandatory. Clone view make same view with page path.

Only solution I can see is create new view and repeat settings (I don't want to do that!), another is to just change path to some useless one so it dons't conflict with my menu links (paths). Any ideas?

Comment: A 'page' view needs a path by definition - if your view shouldn't have a path, you should probably use one of the other display types

Comment: It dose not! You can create one in D7 where you are asked in the beginning (via checkboxes) do you want  support for `page` and/or `block`. I have view without path and I'm using it programmatically. I'm embedding view via `views_embed_view('view_name')`. Display name for my view without page is `master`, where normally you can see something like `page`, `attachment` or `block`. BTW can you point to this definition?

Comment: Proof that view don't need path.
http://postimg.org/image/yp10jn4rn/

Comment: I didn't say a view needs a path - I said a 'page' view needs a path

Comment: So do you understand my problem?

Comment: Not really - if you don't need a page view, just don't create a page view!

Comment: @Clive but the problem is I've already create this page!  And I want to revert from view display type `page` to `master`. Removing `page` display type is the solution, so I don't need to provide path link but still have view to reuse and don't need to create manually again the same view.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a view uncheck Create a page checkbox and check create a block checkbox;

If you already have created a View, you can add new display as shown in figure below:
[image]

Comment: Yes, but I was in opposite situation. I've create view with page (several weeks ago). Tweak `page` display type. After-while I realize I don't want `page` functionality any more and I want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that all you need is to remove current display type, like show on attached screenshot. So when you have only e.g. `page` display type after removal it'll become `master` again.

[image]